# File display top line

Tags: display, pdf

I have inadvertently closed the top line of the pdf display that includes File, Edit, View, Document etc.
this has happened before and it's a simple fix, but I don't remember what I need to od...

Answer (score 0):

Pressing `alt` should show the menu bar (or 'top line' as you call it). Then there should be an option in `view -> toolbars -> menu bar` or something similar to make it stay there permanently depending on the application you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks very much - that seems to have done the trick.  Now I see that F9 also will open and close the top line (unfortunately you can't see that without having the top line open...).